# How to write Sql or LinqToSql for this scenario?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

How to write Sql or LinqToSql for this scenario?

A table has the following data:

```
Id  UserName  Price      Date      Status 

1   Mike    2   2010-4-25 0:00:00   Success
2   Mike    3   2010-4-25 0:00:00   Fail
3   Mike    2   2010-4-25 0:00:00   Success
4   Lily    5   2010-4-25 0:00:00   Success
5   Mike    1   2010-4-25 0:00:00   Fail
6   Lily    5   2010-4-25 0:00:00   Success
7   Mike    2   2010-4-26 0:00:00   Success
8   Lily    5   2010-4-26 0:00:00   Fail
9   Lily    2   2010-4-26 0:00:00   Success
10  Lily    1   2010-4-26 0:00:00   Fail
```

I want to get the summary result from the data, the result should be:

```
UserName    Date   TotalPrice   TotalRecord  SuccessRecord  FailRecord 
Mike      2010-04-25    8            4            2          2
Lily      2010-04-25    10           2            2          0
Mike      2010-04-26    2            1            1          0 
Lily      2010-04-26    8            3            1          2

The TotalPrice is the sum(Price) groupby UserName and Date
The TotalRecord  is the count(*) groupby UserName and Date
The SuccessRecord is the count(*) groupby UserName and Date where Status='Success'
The FailRecord is the count(*) groupby UserName and Date where Status='Fail'
The TotalRecord = SuccessRecord  + FailRecord
```

The sql server 2005 database script is:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Pay]    Script Date: 04/28/2010 22:23:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Pay]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pay](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [UserName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NULL,
 [Price] [int] NULL,
 [Date] [datetime] NULL,
 [Status] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pay] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
END
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (1, N'Mike', 2, CAST(0x00009D6300000000 AS DateTime), N'Success')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (2, N'Mike', 3, CAST(0x00009D6300000000 AS DateTime), N'Fail')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (3, N'Mike', 2, CAST(0x00009D6300000000 AS DateTime), N'Success')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (4, N'Lily', 5, CAST(0x00009D6300000000 AS DateTime), N'Success')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (5, N'Mike', 1, CAST(0x00009D6300000000 AS DateTime), N'Fail')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (6, N'Lily', 5, CAST(0x00009D6300000000 AS DateTime), N'Success')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (7, N'Mike', 2, CAST(0x00009D6400000000 AS DateTime), N'Success')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (8, N'Lily', 5, CAST(0x00009D6400000000 AS DateTime), N'Fail')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (9, N'Lily', 2, CAST(0x00009D6400000000 AS DateTime), N'Success')
INSERT [dbo].[Pay] ([Id], [UserName], [Price], [Date], [Status]) VALUES (10, N'Lily', 1, CAST(0x00009D6400000000 AS DateTime), N'Fail')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Pay] OFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible SQL query would be:

```
SELECT
   UserName
  ,Date
  ,sum(Price)  TotalPay
  ,count(*)  TotalRecord
  ,sum(case Status when 'Success' then 1 else 0 end)  SuccessRecord
  ,sum(case Status when 'Success' then 0 else 1 end)  FailRecord
 from Pay
 group by
   UserName
  ,Date
 order by
   Date
  ,UserName desc
```

This assumes that when Status is NULL, you'd add 1 to FailRecord.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never used Linq. Conversion shouldn't be that tricky...?

Comment: Thank you for your sql, And I have found a Tool (Linqer) to do the conversion job.

Answer (score 1):

Think this does the trick

**UPDATED**

```
var summary = from record in table
              group record by record.UserName + record.Date.ToString() into grp
              select new
              {
                  grp.First().UserName,
                  grp.First().Date,
                  TotalPrice = grp.Sum(record => record.Price),
                  TotalRecord = grp.Count(),
                  SuccessRecord = grp.Count(record => record.Status == "Success"),
                  FailRecord = grp.Count(record => record.Status == "Fail")
              };
```

Comment: Your code gets only two result:
Mike 2010-4-25 0:00:00 10 5 3 2 
Lily 2010-4-25 0:00:00 18 5 3 2

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, only checked that it compiled. I updated my answer with the fix. Couldn't make it work with 2 group by, so I changed the group condition. Now the result is OK.